# Can't control how hours, minutes seconds are formatted using Perl's Datetime::Format::Duration

Tags: perl

The following snippet calculates the duration between two times, but I don't understand how to control the formatted output. In this example, the duration is not output as 00 days, 22 hours, 44 minutes, 03 seconds. Instead, it is output as 00 days, 00 hours, 1364 minutes, 03 seconds. How can I control this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Format::Duration;
use feature 'say';

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
            pattern =>'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            time_zone => 'UTC'
);

my $startDateTime = $parser->parse_datetime('2013-10-13 05:59:44');
my $stopDateTime =  $parser->parse_datetime('2013-10-14 04:43:47');
my $duration = DateTime::Duration->new($stopDateTime-$startDateTime);

my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern => '%d days, %H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds'
);

say $startDateTime;
say $stopDateTime;
say $format->format_duration($duration);
```

Resulting Output:

```
2013-10-13T05:59:44
2013-10-14T04:43:47
00 days, 00 hours, 1364 minutes, 03 seconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $format = DateTime::Format::Duration->new(
    pattern   => '%d days, %H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds',
    normalize => 1,
);

say $format->format_duration($duration);
```

Or to avoid the leading zeros:

```
say sprintf "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds",
   $duration->in_units(qw( days hours minutes seconds ));
```